# MVC - html - select drop down - using GetElementById on drop down causes wrong value to be shown on submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have 2 html dropdowns:

```
<div class="Title">@ViewBag.Title</div>
<form class="Form" method="post">
 <div class="Field Left Size2">
        <span class="Caption">Region</span>
        <select name="Region" onchange="ChangeRegion(this)">
            <option value="">Show all</option>
            @foreach (var each in ActiveRegions)
            {
                <option value="@each.RegionID" @Utility.Control.SelectedIf(Request.Form["Region"] == each.RegionID.ToString())>@each.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>

  <div class="Field Right Size2">
            <span class="Caption">Group by</span>
            <select name="GroupBy">
                <option id="ADOD_PrimaryCampus_MessageStatusReport" value="ADOA Primary Campus" @Utility.Control.SelectedIfFormData("GroupBy", "ADOA Primary Campus")>ADOA Primary Campus</option>
                <option id="SFP_PrimaryCampus_MessageStatusReport" value="SFP Primary Campus" @Utility.Control.SelectedIfFormData("GroupBy", "SFP Primary Campus")>SFP Primary Campus</option>
                <option id="selectOptionManager_MessageStatusReport" value="Manager" @Utility.Control.SelectedIfFormData("GroupBy", "Manager")>Manager</option>
            </select>
        </div>

 <button class="Button Clear Size4" onclick="Go(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which is used in an MVC application inside a `<form class="Form" method="post">` tag.
'Submit' is clicked and results are displayed and everything works as it should...The problem arises when I want 'Manager' in the (second drop down) 'GroupBy' to show or hide depending on what is selected in the first drop down. 'Region'

So far I have tried using js...so from inside the ChangeRegion(this) function I am using document.getElementById()..(I have also tried getElementsByClass but with the same results unfortunately).... so...If 'Online' is selected from the first drop down...hide 'manager' from the second drop down...you should know...the val() for 'Online' in the first drop down is 10..so

```
function ChangeRegion(that) {
//other code..then

   /*If online selected from region, only show 'Manager' from groupBy drop down*/
    var valueSelectedFromRegion = $("[name='Region']");
    if (valueSelectedFromRegion.val() == '10') {
        document.getElementsByClassName('ADAOPrimaryCampus_DD')[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName('SFPPrimaryCampus_DD')[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName('Manager_DD')[0].style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        /*If show all is re-selected (first entry on region) reselect to first entry of group by (which will remove 'Manager' if it was selected)*/
        var valueSelected = $("[name='GroupBy']");
        valueSelected.val('ADOA Primary Campus');

        document.getElementsByClassName('ADAOPrimaryCampus_DD')[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName('SFPPrimaryCampus_DD')[0].style.display = "block";
        document.getElementsByClassName('Manager_DD')[0].style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

So this all works fine...'Manager' is hidden or shown depending on if 'Online' is selected or not...The problem happens when I click submit...so if 'manager' is hidden and only 'ADOD Primary Campus' and 'SFP Primary Campus' is visible...and I choose '**SFP Primary Campus**' and click submit...the page will reload with '**ADOD Primary Campus**' selected...

If I remove the

```
id="ADOD_PrimaryCampus_MessageStatusReport"
id="SFP_PrimaryCampus_MessageStatusReport" 
id="selectOptionManager_MessageStatusReport"
```

from the drop down this issue does not occur?...but then I can not add or show 'Manager' from the drop down

Which is why I also tried GetElementsByClass

has anyone any other suggestions?

thank you

**NOTE All works fine if the GroupBy drop down is fully populated with the 3 items...'ADOA Primary Campus', 'SFP Primary Campus' & 'Manager'
The issue only arises when 'Manager' has been removed from the drop down**

**UPDATE
When I remove the below code that updates the selected value the issue occurs..I need this code because if the first DD value is changed...we need to reomve 'Manager' if it is selected from the second...so I update valueSelected to ADOA **

```
/*If show all is re-selected (first entry on region) reselect to first entry of group by (which will remove 'Manager' if it was selected)*/
    var valueSelected = $("[name='GroupBy']");
    valueSelected.val('ADOA Primary Campus');
```

Comment: The question really is: Why is the page reloading?  Whatever code is reloading the page is not shown in the question.  Please convert this to a [mcve] so that people don't have to fill in the blanks of missing code.

Comment: Im sorry your'e missing the point...or maybe I explained it badly...the page reloads with the results form the search...that is the expected result...whats not expected is the value in the drop down changes if I have an ID attribute set for the items in the DD

Comment: Actually, the code you posted explicitly prevents any request being posted to the server because it returns false from the form's submit handler. (`onclick="Go(); return false;"`).  As far as it's possible to determine the code you have included in your question does not exhibit the behavior you describe.  Please provide a [mcve].